# How to recover deleted video files form Linux Mint?

Tags: data-recovery, linux-mint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover deleted files?](https://superuser.com/questions/132280/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

I have mistakenly deleted some video files. How can I recover those files?

Answer (score -1):

there are various softwares available i will give u a complete guide : [here](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/05/how-to-recover-deleted-files-linux-1/)