# Reset harddisk to previous date

Tags: hard-drive, reset

I lost my Virtual Machine files, which were located in my hard disk.

It is possible to get files from couple days ago back?

Comment: What OS are you using and do you have system restore or backups in place?  If you're not restoring or using backups then probably not.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "lost your files" if they were deleted it **might** be possible. I would try your choice of file recovery software to do the job, file recovery software, is file recovery software.  If your unable to restore the file, and you have no backups, then you are simply out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to get files from couple days ago back?

Yes; it's usually referred to as restoring from backups.

Now, since you are asking this, I suspect that you don't have backups, or if you do have backups, they aren't particularly recent. Unfortunately, that's all too common. In that case, **you *may* be able to use data recovery software** to dig out previously deleted files. However, since it has apparently been a few days since the files were deleted, chances are it's a bit of hit-or-miss as to whether you will be able to make a full recovery. VM disk images are rather finicky, too; if you don't recover everything, chances are far from slim that what's missing will be some critical piece of file system metadata inside the guest, which means that the resulting image file likely will not be usable.

There are numerous posts here already about recovering deleted files. For example, depending on your exact needs, there's [Recover Deleted VHD File](https://superuser.com/q/485732/53590), [How to recover deleted files?](https://superuser.com/q/132280/53590) and [Recover files from deleted partition](https://superuser.com/q/178028/53590). Key something like *recover deleted files* into the search box at the upper right and see what comes up; if you want to really differentiate your question from those, you'll have to be a lot more specific. The problem is compounded by virtual machine disk images tending to be quite large; generally, the larger the file, and the longer it has been since it was deleted (in terms of disk access time), the greater the probability that some part of it has been overwritten.

**Computers don't normally store what the data on disk used to look like some time back.** A few file systems do (the general technical term is normally *Copy-On-Write*, although *log-structured file systems* is another way to accomplish the same goal), but those tend to be of the sort that "if you're using that, you know about it"; one notable file system that is completely based around COW is ZFS, but even with ZFS, it is not guaranteed that you will be able to go back in time unless you use a feature called snapshots and have a relevant snapshot to access. The regulars like NTFS, FAT, ext3fs, Mac HFS+ and so on don't do anything similar. There, the instant a file is deleted, the blocks where it used to be stored are *candidates* for being overwritten by other data (in practice it usually takes some time before the blocks are actually overwritten, but there are no guarantees).